# Jira birthday JQL query

Tags: automation, jira, jql, date

I have multiple issues (people) in a Jira cloud instance and they all have a birthday field.
Now, I'ld like to run a JQL to find out if anyone have a birthday today, so I can remind everyone else. Is this possible?
I also have access to the automation for jira plugin if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your birthday field is a valid date, try `birthday_field >= startOfDay() AND birthday_field < endOfDay` which should give you a result set of *people/issues* with birthday field value that fall today. For additional references, checkout [Function Reference](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/advanced-searching-functions-reference-764478342.html) page.

Comment: Or easier, `birthday_field = now()`. However, it won't work anyway because of different year stored in the field. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this won't be easily possible.

If the field is **date** field (e.g. 11/Dec/1979), the birthday is probably stored including year of birth and therefore time functions (`now()`, `startOfDay()`, ...) won't work.

If the field is **string** field (1979-12-11), then you won't be able to compare it with today as you can get `now()` as a string.

One idea - if you have [ScriptRunner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/6820/scriptrunner-for-jira?hosting=server&tab=overview) installed, create a simple custom scripted field (e.g. Birthday Anniversary) and recalculate original birthday to birthday anniversary this year (11/Dec/2019). You will be then able to compare this field with today, e.g.:

```
"Birthday Anniversary" = now()
```

On top of that, once you are able to create such filter, you can create a custom dashboard with today's birthdays and you can subscribe to this filter and get daily overview of today's birthdays.

Answer (score 0):

In my team we send notification about tickets in the following ways:

1. Jira filters subscription for cases where we need plain(to one person/lead/manager) notification, but without fields analysis

   - https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira064/receiving-search-results-via-email-720416706.html?_ga=2.134616433.1430628443.1592459825-259335427.1591590509
   - https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira064/receiving-search-results-via-email-720416706.html?_ga=2.134616433.1430628443.1592459825-259335427.1591590509
2. https://github.com/dgroup/lazylead for cases where we need automatically check ticket fields, comments, links and alert corresponding person, assignee or reporter.
   Please note that i'm author of https://github.com/dgroup/lazylead app.